# Image artifacts at presentation time on AMD

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

Between the render pass and the end of command buffer I have a compute shader that actually draws to the image.

Before and after that compute shader I have layout transition image barriers:

```
vkCmdEndRenderPass(chain.cmdbuffers[i]);

    imgBars[0].oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    imgBars[0].newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
    imgBars[0].image = chain.images[i];
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(chain.cmdbuffers[i],
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,//render pass doesn't write anything in swapchain image
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, &imgBars[0]);

vkCmdBindPipeline(chain.cmdbuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, pipelines[2]);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(chain.cmdbuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, pipeLayouts[1],
                            0, 1, &chain.descSets[i], 0, 0);
vkCmdDispatch(chain.cmdbuffers[i], chain.dim.width/32, chain.dim.height/32, 1);

    imgBars[0].oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL;
    imgBars[0].newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
    imgBars[0].image = chain.images[i];
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    imgBars[0].subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    imgBars[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT;
    imgBars[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(chain.cmdbuffers[i],
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT,
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, &imgBars[0]);
vkEndCommandBuffer(chain.cmdbuffers[i]);
```

Renderdoc shows that the draw works as it should - no artifacts, the image is drawn at the dispatch command. The image is being drawn relatively fine in some parts, but otherwise it has squares the size of compute shader work groups(it writes to the coordinate equal to its global invocation ID) of garbage. The presentation command takes a semaphore that is being signaled by the command buffer that draws to the image. Both presentation and commands are submitted to the same queue, though it probably doesn't matter.

It works fine on nVidia gpu

From this I can only assume that the driver signals semaphore before actually completing the compute command, or I miss/do wrong a synchronisation somewhere.